# SQL - Need to GROUP BY only one column of SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql

**This is the dataset I'm using:**

| country_or_area | year | comm_code | commodity | flow | trade_usd | weight_kg | quantity_name | quantity | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgium | 2016 | 920510 | Brass-wind instru... | Export | 571297 | 3966.0 | Number of items | 4135.0 | 92_musical_instru... |
| Guatemala | 2008 | 660200 | Walking-sticks, s... | Export | 35022 | 5575.0 | Number of items | 10089.0 | 66_umbrellas_walk... |
| Barbados | 2006 | 220210 | Beverage waters, ... | Re-Export | 81058 | 44458.0 | Volume in litres | 24113.0 | 22_beverages_spir... |
| Tunisia | 2016 | 780411 | Lead foil of a th... | Import | 4658 | 121.0 | Weight in kilograms | 121.0 | 78_lead_and_artic... |
| Lithuania | 1996 | 560110 | Sanitary towels, ... | Export | 76499 | 5419.0 | Weight in kilograms | 5419.0 | 56_wadding_felt_n... |

**This is the question I need to answer:**

The most commercialized commodity (by occurrencies) in 2016, per flow type

**I need to group by flow only, but I don't know how can I do it.**

```
query = '''
        SELECT flow, commodity, MAX(quantity) quantity
        FROM (
          SELECT flow, commodity, COUNT(*) quantity
          FROM transactions
          WHERE year = 2016
          GROUP BY flow, commodity
        )
        GROUP BY flow
        '''
spark.sql(query).show(10)
```

**The result I'm expecting is something like this:**

```
[('Export', ('Sweet biscuits, waffles and wafers', 24)),
 ('Import', ('Baking powders, prepared', 27)),
 ('Re-Export', ('Glues or adhesives, prepared nes, package > 1kg', 8)),
 ('Re-Import', ('Footwear,sole rubber/plastic,upper textile, not sport', 5))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `ROW_NUMBER`, ordering by `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT flow, commodity, cnt
FROM (
  SELECT flow, commodity, 
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY flow, commodity ORDER BY COUNT(*)) rn
  FROM transactions
  WHERE year = 2016
  GROUP BY flow, commodity
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

or alternatively use `MAX`, yet comparing when your count value is equal to the max value

```
SELECT flow, commodity, cnt
FROM (
  SELECT flow, commodity, 
         COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY flow, commodity) maxcnt
  FROM transactions
  WHERE year = 2016
  GROUP BY flow, commodity
)
WHERE cnt = maxcnt
```

although the former is likely to perform a nudge better.

Comment: Without 'commodity' into PARTITION BY it works as expected. Your query works correctly when there are more than one result with the same 'maxcnt'. Thanks!

Comment: There's an issue when you remove the commodity from the partition by: your output would be correct only by chance, because the count will work on both flow and commodity, while the rownumber will work on flow only. Unless you aggregate commodity as well in the subquery.

Comment: This issue exists in the other solution, which is essentially wrong (gives correct results by chance) for this reason.

Comment: Got it, I used the 'max' alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window function`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-partition-by)
This will give you flow, commodity where quantity is maximum, and max of quantity over each distinct commdity

```
SELECT distinct 
flow, 
first_value(commodity) over(partition by flow order by quantity desc), 
MAX(quantity) over(partition by flow) as quantity_max
FROM (
  SELECT flow, commodity, COUNT(*) quantity
  FROM transactions
  WHERE year = 2016
  GROUP BY flow, commodity
)
```

Comment: I was expecting a result like this:
```
[('Export', ('Sweet biscuits, waffles and wafers', 24)),
 ('Import', ('Baking powders, prepared', 27)),
 ('Re-Export', ('Glues or adhesives, prepared nes, package > 1kg', 8)),
 ('Re-Import', ('Footwear,sole rubber/plastic,upper textile, not sport', 5))]
```

Comment: I see, so you want the value where the commodity is maximum as well?

Comment: Yes, one row for each flow type with the most comercialized commodity and it's occurencies.

Comment: Updated my answer, seems like others have also answered :)

Comment: Uhmm, this works as expected but it's returning the wrong commodity.

Comment: Ah missed a desc keyword my bad, `order by quantity desc`. sorry about that